# Cannot access Swift Package xcassets

Tags: swift, swift-package-manager, swift-package

I'm trying to use a color set from a `xcassets` folder that is inside a Swift Package ([src](https://github.com/kelvinlauKL/GoodPackage)). It doesn't seem to be working. I tested this out by writing a simple view that attempts to make use of the color:

```
Text("Hello")
  .foregroundColor(Color("brandPrimary")
```

I got an empty view from this code; the text can't find the color.

I've done significant research around the web - reviewing WWDC videos such as [Swift packages: Resources and localization](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10169/), and they seem to suggest that `xcassets` folder are automatically included as resources. It doesn't work for me.

I tried to add `process("Resources/Colors.xcassets")` inside my [package manifest](https://github.com/kelvinlauKL/GoodPackage/blob/master/Package.swift), but that didn't help either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the `Color` documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/color/init(_:bundle:)):

> `init(_ name: String, bundle: Bundle? = nil)`
>
> …
>
> **`bundle`**
>
> > The bundle in which to search for the color resource. If you don’t indicate a bundle, the initializer looks in your app’s main bundle by default.

Your GoodPackage library's assets are not the app's main bundle, so you need to tell the `Color` initializer which bundle to search.

The Swift package manager's build process automatically creates a `Bundle` for each target/module that contains assets. Within the module, you can access that generated `Bundle` using the expression `Bundle.module`. SwiftPM actually writes Swift code to a file named `resource_bundle_accessor.swift` in your DerivedData to make this work. The generated source code looks like this:

```
import class Foundation.Bundle
import class Foundation.ProcessInfo
import struct Foundation.URL

private class BundleFinder {}

extension Foundation.Bundle {
    /// Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module.
    static let module: Bundle = {
        let bundleName = "YourPackageName_YourTargetName"

        let overrides: [URL]
        #if DEBUG
        if let override = ProcessInfo.processInfo.environment["PACKAGE_RESOURCE_BUNDLE_URL"] {
            overrides = [URL(fileURLWithPath: override)]
        } else {
            overrides = []
        }
        #else
        overrides = []
        #endif

        let candidates = overrides + [
            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
            Bundle.main.resourceURL,

            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
            Bundle(for: BundleFinder.self).resourceURL,

            // For command-line tools.
            Bundle.main.bundleURL,
        ]

        for candidate in candidates {
            let bundlePath = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleName + ".bundle")
            if let bundle = bundlePath.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
                return bundle
            }
        }
        fatalError("unable to find bundle named YourPackageName_YourTargetName")
    }()
}
```

As you can see, that `static let module` property has (default) internal access, so you can only use it from source code within that module. By default, there is no way to access the module's `Bundle` from outside the module.

One solution is to add a public accessor for the module `Bundle` in the GoodPackage module. For example, add this to a source file in the GoodPackage module:

```
import Foundation

extension Bundle {
    public var GoodPackage: Bundle { Bundle.module }
}
```

Then, in your app:

```
import GoodPackage

...

    Text("Hello")
        .foregroundColor(Color("brandPrimary", bundle: .GoodPackage))
```

Comment: Sir, you just made my week.